# Can a person with a heart transplant fly safely, or should they consider an alternative form of transportation?

Tags: travel, aviation, heart-transplant, organ-donation, barotrauma

Could a person who had received a heart transplant move to/travel to another country (for example: From France to the United States)?

The caveat being that they would have to set up another team of doctors to monitor the progress of the donor heart if they decided to become a permanent resident of their new country, possibly set up a medical translator to translate any records or conversations between the previous team of doctors to the new one, and that it would have been a few years since the surgery with no notable issues with the transplant.

Would it be safe for air travel, or would another conveyance be more desirable (which would be by ship at that point)?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to health.SE! You've basically answered your own question... are you trying to ask if it's safe for a person with a heart transplant to travel?

Comment: Yes. Would it be safe for air travel, or would another conveyance be more desirable (which would be by ship at that point)?